# Connected sum minus a point is homotopy equivalent to connected sum of spaces each with a point taken out?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I.e. if your spaces are $X_1, \dots, X_m$, then is
$$
\bigl(X_1 \mathbin{\#} \cdots \mathbin{\#} X_m \bigr) \backslash \{p\}
$$
homotopy equivalent to
$$
\bigl(X_1 \backslash {p_1}\bigr) \mathbin{\#} \cdots 
\mathbin{\#} \bigl(X_m \backslash \{p_m\}\bigr)?
$$
(Here, $p$ is any point in the connected sum and $p_i$ is a point in $X_i$.)

This seems true by looking at fundamental polygons but I'm not sure about nailing down a full argument.

(First post here, please be kind.)

Comment: What have you tried? How about a small example, say in dimension $2$ (surfaces) and with $m=2$? Can you visualize the homotopy? Does it generalize?

Comment: This already fails for dimension $1$. Consider $X_1=X_2=\mathbb{R}$. Then $(X_1\#X_2)\backslash\{p\}$ has three connected components while $(X_1\backslash\{p_1\})\#(X_2\backslash\{p_2\})$ has four components, regardless of the choice of points and the way we perform connected sum.